# How can I get all contacts with a mobile phone number using Contacts framework in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, contacts

I'm using `try contactStore.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate` with the key `CNContactPhoneNumbersKey` but I'm not sure what `NSPredicate` to use to simply accept all the `CNContact`s with a non-nil `CNContactPhoneNumbersKey`.

Comment: That method will return one contact with a certain identifier. Have you looked at the rest of the methods to find one that returns all contacts?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enumerate through the whole contact store as the predicates are not flexible enough yet:

```
var contactsWithPhoneNumber = [CNContact]()
let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey])
try! contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest) { contact, stop in
    if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
        contactsWithPhoneNumbers.append(contact)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I even tried to use `NSPredicate(value: true)` but  to no avail. Thanks!